How to modify filepath of a database file that is inside a file group
How do you modify filepath of a database file that is inside a filegroup?
Just the normal and direct way?
Alter database []
Modify file (name='', newfilepath='')

Or
Alter database []
Modify filegroup []
Modify file (name='', newfilepath='')


The first one. (Logical) File names are unique to the database.

Every data file is a member of a file group. Even the first one that is created with the database is part of the Primary File Group. So yes, same way as with any other file.

Both options are incorrect.
For the first option newfilepath do not exists. Use FILENAME instead
From Move User Databases (Microsoft Learn | SQL)
ALTER DATABASE mydatabase_name 
    MODIFY FILE ( 
                  NAME = logical_name, 
                  FILENAME = 'new_path\os_file_name'
                );

